# How are the default AOSP launcher shortcuts installed in a ROM build?

Tags: android, android-source, android-launcher

I'm building my own version of AOSP (using code from the [Code Aurora](https://www.codeaurora.org/projects/all-active-projects/android-msm) repos for a custom device) and trying to determine how shortcuts to certain apps are being added automatically to the launcher's db (Launcher3 on Marshmallow to be more specific). I want to change these around and remove/reposition some of them. (In this particular instance the apps in question are those from the GMS suite.)

I understand that apps can try to get their shortcuts onto the launcher's workspace by sending a [ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT) intent. Are some of these apps sending these intents after first boot but before the launcher launches for the first time?

I couldn't find any steps or code that adds these values to the db as a prestep at build time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the "`workspace`" of the launcher which located under `platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/res/xml/default_workspace_*.xml`.([here](https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/tree/res/xml?h=LA.AF.1.1.1))
You will notice there are different workspace for different screen sizes (e.g 4X4 / 5X5 / 5X6).
To add new apps just add the next tag:

```
<favorite
    launcher:packageName="com.android.gallery3d" //Your app name
    launcher:className="com.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery" // Your launcher Activity
    launcher:screen="3" // The screen number
    launcher:x="1" // X Location on screen
    launcher:y="3" /> // Y Location on screen
```

**Xml tags -**
1. `favorite` - Specific app.
2. `resolve` - Resolve default app (e.g default messages app) 
3. `appwidget` - Widget...

[AOSP original link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/android-6.0.1_r61/res/xml/)

Comment: How to verify screen size of  device?

Comment: How to add folder ?