# Enhance Android launcher 3 code

Tags: android, user-interface, android-source

I am new to Android UI design. Can I know how to add Workspace in launcher 3 code. By default there is only one Screen. How to add more screens.Create two new pages (accessible by swiping to the left from the Homescreen).

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265211/562139) should be a good starting point. Gist is that this information is located here: `[root]/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/res/xml/default_workspace_*.xml`.